# An issue using the 'CALL' command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, subroutine, method-call

## Problem Summary

In the process of trying to automate a task in my Windows computer using a Batch script to do so, i ran into an issue so basically in the batch script i have two procedures one called `:main` and the other one `:str_len`.

The `:ste_len` procedure receives two arguments (*Rem: From an algorithmic perspective the first one is considered a string and the second one an integer*) when called from the `:main` procedure and what is does is calculates the length of the 'string' and then stores it into its second argument, the problem i am having is that i don't know how to reference a variable using batch, like a way to create some sort of variable pointer in the `:main` part and then sending this pointer to the `:str_len` part  using the `call` command, kinda like what we call a passage by address in the C programming language.

## What i tried

I tried declaring the variable `length` using the `set` command thinking if i do so then it's name without any `%` would be a direct pointer to it, but my assumption was wrong.

Also to reach my goal i tried to use the call command twice the first time from the `:main` to `:str_len` and the second time from `:str_len` to a sub routine of main that will receive the necessary data and prints it (process it), the reason why i didn't opt for this solution is mainly, because  i am working on a bigger problem that requires multiple procedures to operate throw (this question is about one of the procedures), and most of them need some sort of collaboration (a procedure uses the output of another in order to be able to work) so as you might have guessed the second solution will render my code really ambiguous.

#### Second solution with two procedures:

```
@echo off
title test

:main
    set string=%1
    set /A l=0
    call :str_len %string%
        :return_str_len
            echo the string "%string%" is %1 characters long!
            goto :eof
    goto :eof

:str_len
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set str=%1
    if "%str%"=="!str:~0,%i%!" (
        call return_str_len %i%
        endlocal
        goto :eof
    ) else (
        set /A i+=1
        goto str_len
    )
```

## What i did so far:

```
@echo off
title test

:main
    set string=%1
    set /A l=0
    call :str_len %string% length
    echo The string "%string%" is %length% characters long!
    goto :eof

:str_len
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set str=%1
    if "%str%"=="!str:~0,%i%!" (
        set %2=%i%
        endlocal
        goto :eof
    ) else (
        set /A i+=1
        goto str_len
    )
```

## Expected and actual results:

what i expected the above code to output was something like this:

```
>test.bat Hello
The String "Hello" is 5 characters long!
```

but what it does actually outputs is this:

```
>test.bat
The string "Hello" is  characters long!
```

## Questions:

1)-Is there a way to create a pointer to a variable in batch and if yes then how do i combine it with the call command to get the result i am trying to get?

2)-If the answer to question number one is 'nope' then can you please tell me of a work around that will give me a result that is close enough to what i intend to reach using Batch.

Comment: You cannot refer to an argument reference like  `%1` outside of the sub-routine, so in your last approach it should read `echo The string "%string%" is %length% characters long!`. And do not `call` back from the sub-routine to the main one!

Comment: Ah, and `set %2=%i%` (or better `set "%~2=%i%"`) must be put *after* `endlocal`...

Comment: Why reinvent the [wheel](https://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#strLen)?

Comment: @aschipfl First thanks for your comments, in the first one you addressed how i should not reference an argument reference like %1 outside the sub-routine and that in my last approach it should read the instruction that you typed instead of mine in that you are right and i corrected (i was a typing error) in the second one however i do not understand why ```set "%~2=%i%"```  is considered better then ``` set %2=%i%``` also why does it have to be after the endlocal ?

Comment: 1. the quoted syntax `set "VAR=Value"` is generally better as special characters are protected and unintended trailing white-spaces are prevented; `%~2` removes potential surrounding quotes to avoid "over-quotation". 2. `setlocal` begins environment localisation, meaning that all environment changes, like set/changed/cleared variables and current working directory are valid until the next `endlocal` (or script or sub-routine end, which implies `endlocal`), so doing `set "%~2=%i%"` before `endlocal` is useless as this assignment was then lost...

Comment: ohh i see thanks for the tip